# Issue with List Apply in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

`Unable to find a matching line for sublist apply with key: [doc,line] and value: [5489377,1].`

I'm seeing this error when I try to update an apply list on a NetSuite transaction object. The "doc" is the internal ID of the object, and the line number seems to correspond to a line number on the object.

Why is this happening? Can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: what type of script. What record type are you trying to update? Normally you start with a credit memo or customer payment and the apply lines are already all filled in with invoice ids. You can check the apply flag and update the amount but you can't actually add a line to the apply list.

Comment: I'm writing this via Java with the SOAP wsdl. I'm trying to apply a credit memo to an open invoice. When I look at the memo in the UI, I'm not seeing any pre-populated invoice ids in the apply tab.

Comment: You might want to check the invoice status in the UI as well. Haven't ever done an apply with SuiteTalk.

Answer (score 0):

This works for applying a credit memo to a particular invoice. invId is the internalid of the invoice record:

```
function applyPayment(creditMemo, payAmount, invId){
    var didApply = false;
    creditMemo.setFieldValue('autoapply', 'F');
    if(payAmount === null) payAmount = creditMemo.getFieldValue('amountremaining');
    for(var i = 1; i<=creditMemo.getLineItemCount('apply'); i++){
        if(invId == creditMemo.getLineItemValue('apply', 'doc', i)){
            didApply = true;
            creditMemo.setLineItemValue('apply', 'apply', i, 'T');
            creditMemo.setLineItemValue('apply', 'amount',i, payAmount);
        }else if('T' == creditMemo.getLineItemValue('apply', 'apply', i)) creditMemo.setLineItemValue('apply', 'apply', i, 'F');
    }
    if(didApply) nlapiSubmitRecord(creditMemo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error with the Chargebee-Netsuite integration and the solution was to open the corresponding Accounting Period in Netsuite and rerun the sync.

Like you mentioned, the first number[5489377,1] is the Netsuite internal ID of the affected document. If you navigate to the document in Netsuite and it has a padlock this could be the reason [Locked document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrtXn.png)

Open the Accounting Period for the affected document and rerun the sync. setup/accounting/manage accounting periods [Manage accounting periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie1o9.png)